# driver.find_elements by tagname of "a" is showing blank results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, ui-automation

So I got a python **selenium version 4.15.2** script where I am opening this web page:

https://app.logrocket.com/

And I just want to simply fetch all the hyperlinks available in the page and store it in a collection.

But, it shows that there is no available hyperlinks in the page even though there is.

Below is the code:

```
driver.get("https://app.logrocket.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
abc = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')
```

The variable "abc" just shows blank.

Any suggestions will be helpful for me?

Expecting all hyperlinks which generally starts `from tagname as a` should be stored in `abc` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One of the most fundamental aspects of using Selenium is obtaining
> element references to work with.

`abc` will be a `list` of references to your selected elements, to get specific [information about one or multiple referenced elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/information/) you have to iterate the references and query the needed details.

---

Your code should work - keep in mind that the website you provided needs a login, so far you just would be able to scrape two `<a>`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://app.logrocket.com/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a'))) 
  
for e in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a'):
    print(e.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Output:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Up</a>
<a class="auth0-lock-alternative-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Don't remember your password?</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... here why its not fetching all the tags at once in below line

abc = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')

why a forloop needs to be run in order to get those tags?
without forloop why we cant fetch and save the tags data using below line

abc = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')

Comment: Because you just find references to elements from the DOM in your `abc` and have to query specific details about it.

Comment: i believe its not the case when we use JAVA
in java we can specify the varaible type ex. ArrayList<Webelement> and it will store those 2 elements
but in python its not the same?